# How to format files on save using black with neovim and coc

Tags: neovim, formatting, filetype-python, plugin-coc, debugging

I'm trying to have python files format on save using black and neovim, with coc.

### Coc config

I have the following  coc config:

```
{
  "coc.preferences.useQuickfixForLocations": true,
  "coc.preferences.snippets.enable": true,

  // python config
  "python.venvFolders": [".virtualenvs"],
  "python.venvPath" : "~/",
  "python.linting.enabled": true,
  "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
  "python.jediEnabled": false,
  "python.formatting.provider": "black",
  "python.formatting.blackPath": "~/.virtualenvs/neovim/bin/black",
  "coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": ["python"]
}
```

### Venv packages

Within the venv above I have the following black version:

```
-> % which python
/Users/x/.virtualenvs/neovim/bin/python

(neovim) x@y [14:31:38] [~/.virtualenvs]
-> % pip list | grep black
black           19.10b0
```

Other packages in this env are:

```
-> % pip list
Package         Version
--------------- ---------
appdirs         1.4.4
attrs           19.3.0
black           19.10b0
click           7.1.2
greenlet        0.4.16
isort           5.1.4
jedi            0.17.2
msgpack         1.0.0
neovim          0.3.1
numpy           1.19.1
pandas          1.0.5
parso           0.7.1
pathspec        0.8.0
pip             20.1.1
pynvim          0.4.1
python-dateutil 2.8.1
pytz            2020.1
regex           2020.7.14
setuptools      41.2.0
six             1.15.0
toml            0.10.1
typed-ast       1.4.1
```

### Behaviour / errors

I see no errors, but I see no results. For example I would expect the following
to work given that setup is functioning:

```py
# from
print('hi')
# to (having saved file)
print("hi")
```

I don't get this though, nothing happens.

Something unusual that *does* happen is that my buffer for a python file is
constantly in need of saving. By which I mean - I *constantly* have `No write since last change` warning when trying to do `:q`, which makes me think there's
something funny going on, but I don't know where.

## Edit

Here is the output of `:checkhealth`

## Edit 2

Black seems to be working, for me, these are settings that I currently have.

**coc-settings.json**

```
   "python.formatting.provider": "black",
   "python.formatting.blackPath": "~/.virtualenvs/neovim/bin/black",
   "coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": ["python"]
```

I also have nothing of the `psf/black` plugin anymore, that was (i think)
causing some issues.

Comment: For what it's worth, I use ALE w/ black enabled for python and fix-on-save, and I never have issues with black.

Comment: I think coc config json files only take absolute path, so `~` should not work. Anyway, have you solved the issue?

Comment: i've not solved anything unfortunately

Comment: I need to correct my comment: I just confirmed `~` works (doesn't have to be absolute path). Also, after a long day of investigating this workflow for myself, I finally managed to understand the setup and it works for now. Are you interested in an answer here? If so I'll try to write up a setup process as answer.

Comment: @GordonBai if you have an answer that'd be great

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a `coc.nvim` setup procedure that works for Neovim, which aims to:

- Use `coc-pyright` as language server.
- Provide static type checking from a Python virtualenv (*e.g.* I have created a venv called `coc` with `pyenv`, which resides in `~/.pyenv/versions`, I'll use this as an example).
- Format with `black` manually and automatically on save.

So here is my setup procedure:

1. Configure venv in `coc-settings.json`:

   ```json
   {
     "python.venvPath": "/Users/gbai/.pyenv/versions"
   }
   ```

   Here an absolute path is necessary for now, see this [issue comment](https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright/issues/189).

   **Update**: You could use `${env:HOME}` (no space after `:`!) to replace `~`:

   ```json
   {
     "python.venvPath": "${env:HOME}/.pyenv/versions"
   }
   ```
2. Choose a Python language server:

   Per `coc.nvim`'s [official doc section](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/wiki/Language-servers#python), I installed [`coc-pyright`](https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright) as language server by

   ```
   :CocInstall coc-pyright
   ```

   It has its own config file `pyrightconfig.json` per project, and should be placed at project root. I simply put this line in `pyrightconfig.json`:

   ```json
   {
     "venv": "coc"
   }
   ```

   Of course for different project, the venv differs.
3. Configure `black`

   Install `black` in the venv (`coc` in my config), and add these to `coc-settings.json`:

   ```json
   {
     "python.formatting.provider": "black",
     "python.formatting.blackPath": "~/.pyenv/versions/coc/bin/black"
   }
   ```

   Interestingly, I can use relative path `~` here without problem.
4. Formatting

   As per this [issue comment](https://github.com/neoclide/coc-python/issues/63#issuecomment-515722002):

   > - Use `"coc.preferences.formatOnType": true` to enable format on type feature.
   > - Use `"coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": ["python"]` to include filetypes you want format on save.
   > - Use `:call CocAction('format')` to format currrent document.
   > - Use
   >
   >   ```
   >   xmap <leader>f  <Plug>(coc-format-selected)
   >   nmap <leader>f  <Plug>(coc-format-selected)
   >   ```
   >
   >   to format selected range.

   To inspect if formatting went well, as per this [issue comment](https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright/issues/220#issuecomment-751626842):

   > coc-pyright v1.1.97 adds more formatting logs, you can get it by: `:CocCommand workspace.showOutput` - `coc-pyright-formatting`.

   through which you can tell if `black` is loaded and run correctly.
5. Some more info

   Apart from using `"coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": ["python"]` as mentioned above, also see this [issue comment](https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright/issues/229#issuecomment-794788144) and another [issue comment](https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-pyright/issues/424#issuecomment-812846192):

   > The latest coc has added `coc.preferences.willSaveHandlerTimeout`, the default is 500ms, you can increase this time limitation.

   This is useful especially when you have very large files, which takes long to format.

Yes I have referenced a few issue comments where the actually instructions are. Maybe they should have a more detailed documentation :)

Comment: From the `coc-pyright` docs you can add an array to `"python.formatting.blackArgs"`, e.g. `: ["-l", "79"]`, to your `coc-settings.json` to specify arguments to black, as well.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue. I solved it as below:

1. Don't use black and isort from inside coc. Coc timeout issue mentioned by @Gorden Bai seems unresolved.
   My coc-settings.json:

```json
{
    "python.sortImports.path": "/usr/bin/isort",
    "coc.preferences.willSaveHandlerTimeout": 1000,
    // this is required. Else coc looks for autopep8
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.formatting.blackPath": "/usr/bin/black",
    // removed python from below to run black and isort independently
    "coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": [
        "json",
        "markdown"
    ],
    "coc.source.around.firstMatch": false,
    "pyright.enable": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Path": "flake8",
    "python.linting.enabled": true 
}
```

2. In init.vim:

> ```
> call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
> Plug 'psf/black', { 'branch': 'main' }
> Plug 'fisadev/vim-isort'
> call plug#end()
>
> " This triggers all formatting before coc linter is triggered
> aug python
>     au!
>     autocmd BufWritePre *.py Isort
>     autocmd BufWritePre *.py Black
> aug END
> ```

P.S. I am not using virtual environment.

Comment: Welcome to the site Ashwin.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need `coc` to format on save.

See the official document: https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/integrations/editors.html#vim

After install `black` as a vim plugin, add this line in your `.vimrc`

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.py execute ':Black'
```

Or as @D.Ben Knoble pointed out

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.py Black
```

Comment: In fact you don’t need execute there

Comment: It errors if I remove `execute`

Comment: `autocmd BufWritePre *.py Black` ?

Comment: I see, thanks. I was only copying from their tutorial